# problem with qgsmaptoolpan

Tags: qgis, api, c++, pan, maptools

i am using the c++ api qgis 2.8.2
i have a strange problem when i want to use the pantool for my canvas

i used this code :

```
mpPanTool = new QgsMapToolPan((QgsMapCanvas*)mpMapCanvas);
((QgsMapToolPan*)mpPanTool)->activate();
((QgsMapCanvas*)mpMapCanvas)->setMapTool((QgsMapToolPan*)mpPanTool);
```

building is good, 
when i launch my application and i load a raster or a s57 map
if i click on the map or on the canvas nothing happen till i move the mouse
when i move the mouse it seems that the map change the upper left origin point and set a new one at the mouse position
by example if i left click on the map and i move the mouse, the map is automatically centered with the upper left point of the canvas at the mouse coordinate

perhaps i forget something, pan works but the problem is this coordinate change

please help

Answer (score 1):

i have found a solution
in my application  i have a raster, and i want to pan the raster

here is the code i have

```
void CMyQgsMapCanvas::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* pevent)
{

    mMouseEvent = new QMouseEvent(pevent->type() , pevent->pos(), pevent->globalPos(), pevent->button(),pevent->buttons(), pevent->modifiers() );
    mClickTimer.start(220);
    qDebug() << "Button ::" << mMouseEvent->button();

    if ( pevent->button() == Qt::LeftButton )
    {
        mCanvasProperties->panSelectorDown = true;

        QPoint  lPos = pevent->pos();
        mCanvasProperties->rubberStartPoint = lPos;
    }
    pevent->ignore();
}

void CMyQgsMapCanvas::mouseReleaseEvent( QMouseEvent* pevent)
{
    mLeftButtonPressed=false;
    if ( pevent->button() == Qt::LeftButton )
    {
        mCanvasProperties->panSelectorDown = false;
        mCanvasProperties->mouseButtonDown = false;
    }
    pevent->ignore();
}

void CMyQgsMapCanvas::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* pevent)
{

    QPoint  lPos = pevent->pos();

    if(mCanvasProperties->mouseButtonDown == true)
    {
        panActionEnd(lPos);
        mCanvasProperties->rubberStartPoint = lPos;
    }

    setCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor);
    QgsMapCanvas::mouseMoveEvent(pevent);
    pevent->ignore();
}
```

it works well
after loading the raster in the mapcanvas i can move it by moving the mouse keeping the left button pressed